# Map memory data garbled in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11

I define a global map `map<string, int> sourceMap` to record the mapping between the line number and the source line.
There are problems:

**1)When I iterate the map if I print the src first and the number second, the print is garbled. However, the reverse is normal.**

Garbled outputs and codes:

```
**codes:**
for (auto item = sourceMap.begin(); item != sourceMap.end(); item++) {
                cout << "line: " << item->first<< ", line2number:"<<sourceMap[item->first]<<endl;
            }


**outputs:**
, line2number:8dminInterface
, line2number:30payable{}
, line2number:14minInterface(){
, line2number:24t(addressdataBase)payableonlyOwner
, line2number:36dOwner(addressnewAddr)payable
, line2number:32ansfer(addressmultisig)payableonlyOwner{
line: msg.value>Limit, line2number:38
, line2number:33ransfer(msg.value);
, line2number:44ansfer(this.balance);
, line2number:41egatecall(bytes4(keccak256("AddToWangDB(address)")),msg.sender);
```

Normal outputs and codes of the reverse:

```
**code:**
 for (auto item = sourceMap.begin(); item != sourceMap.end(); item++) {
      cout << "line2number:"<<sourceMap[item->first] << ",line: " << item->first <<endl;
}

**outputs:**
line2number:32,line: functiontransfer(addressmultisig)payableonlyOwner{
line2number:38,line: msg.value>Limit
line2number:33,line: multisig.transfer(msg.value);
line2number:44,line: newAddr.transfer(this.balance);
line2number:41,line: oracle.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("AddToWangDB(address)")),msg.sender);
line2number:27,line: oracle=dataBase;
line2number:7,line: pragmasolidity^0.4.18;
line2number:19,line: require(msg.sender==Owner);
line2number:12,line: uint256publicLimit;
line2number:39,line: {
```

**2) The map cannot find the corresponding value of many keys.**

the abnormal outputs:
'''
number: 0, new_line: oracle.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("AddToWangDB(address)")),msg.sender);
'''

and the normal outputs:
'''
number: 38, new_line: msg.value>Limit
'''

A phrase of the corresponding codes:

```
 while (getline(blockText, lllline)){
       remove_escapesALL(lllline);
       cout<<"number: "<<sourceMap[lllline]<<", new_line: "<<lllline<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: The source lines end with `\r` which is somehow not filtered out. The `\r` (also called: carriage return) is somehow invisible but moves the cursor to begin of line. Hence, following output overwrites what was printed before. I once noticed that `getline()` removes the delimiter (`\n` by default) but not the `\r`. This becomes a problem if e.g. texts written in Windows (with `\r\n` line ends) are processed on Linux (where `\n` is usual). (I once tapped myself into this trap.) ;-)

Comment: Please edit question and add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example so we can undestand what is going on.

Comment: If my guess is correct, this would be a fix (has to be applied to the read string `text` after `std::getline()`): `if (text.size() && text.back() == '\r') text.pop_back();`. [**Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/289a86acff24dfae) (The online editor of coliru seems to store `\r\n` as well as I once found out.)

Comment: @Scheff Thanks very much!!! it worked!!! The problem is indeed caused by  '\r'. Inspired by you, I replace the "\r" with " "  for each new string line if I find it. I think the main problem  originates from the that I use Clion in Windows host to  develop codes and organize data sets in the remote server

Comment: Because the codes once worked well on data sets, but suddenly not worked. It may be caused by that these data files are repeatedly manipulated in Windows.

Comment: I'm doing my daily business in Windows by carefully trying to stay portable to other platforms as well. Line ending issues caused by the one or other Windows editor are my daily pain. ;-)